# Arrow Pointing to Each Line of Form

Tags: css, tooltip, css-transitions

In my sign up form for my website, I want to make a tooltip kind of thing for my form, but I want an arrow constructed from css3.  I haven't the foggiest clue how to do this kind of thing.

Essentially, when input:focus, a triangle (rendered with CSS3) would move up, or down, in a transition, to point at that input text field.  Is this feasible?  How?  Thank you.

I'd like to make it completely out of CSS, not jQuery or JavaScript.  I'm trying to avoid using JavaScript as much as possible so as not to use bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do triangles with relative ease via borders. [This demo](http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/) is probably my favorite on the subject, and it goes through creating a chat/tooltip bubble in CSS.

You can get a lot more creative than that, though: http://jsfiddle.net/czuxH/

I wouldn't worry too much about saving bandwidth by cutting out minimal snippets of JavaScript — it's just text, and properly minified and gzipped it really isn't much bandwidth. You're going to need JS here to trigger the animations and position the arrow (though you can use CSS3 animations to do the transition).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it strictly without JavaScript because a selector incorporating `:focus` can only select descendent elements beyond the `:focus` pseudo selector, and `input` elements are *empty* elements. You also can't use pseudo-elements because `input` elements are *replaced* elements.

You could do it with a *touch* of JavaScript to add the elements on the event.

```
var input = document.getElementsByName('some_input')[0],
    parent = input.parentNode,
    bubble = document.createElement('div');

bubble.className = 'bubble';
bubble.textContent = 'Your text.';
parent.appendChild(bubble);

input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    parent.className += ' focus';
});

input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    parent.className = parent.className.replace(/\bfocus\b/, '');
});
```

Comment: "because :focus can only select descendent elements, and input elements are empty elements." ... what? Pseudo-classes don't select descendants, that's what the descendant combinator does.

Comment: @bolt yeah, bad wording on my behalf.